# ListPolarPlot Labelling Points on the Plot

Tags: plotting

I have created a ListPolarPlot using the code below. I need to label the lines that extend from the centre to the outer ring. I do not want to label them with the values that these lines represent but rather with the values 1 to 7. I have tried LabelingFunction and some other things but these options don't work for ListPolarPlot. Can anyone help me with this ?

As a second best solution I could just label the plotted points themselves from 1 to 7 (starting at the right hand horizontal and working anticlockwise).

```
ListPolarPlot[
 Tooltip /@ {0.01422, 0.3425217, 0.30036, 0.013, 0.152, 0.3762, 
   0.122}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics@Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[0.025]], 
 Axes -> {True, False}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
 PolarGridLines -> {{0.897, 0.897*2, 0.897*3, 0.897*4, 0.897*5, 
    0.897*6, 0.897*7}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}}, PolarTicks -> None, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/1, ImageSize -> {300, 300}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for any number of points:

```
lpp[l_List] := ListPolarPlot[Tooltip /@ l,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> Graphics@Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[0.025]],
  Axes -> {True, False},
  PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
  PolarGridLines -> {Array[2 Pi #/Length@l &, Length@l], {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}}, 
  PolarTicks -> Transpose[{Array[2 Pi #/Length@l &, Length@l], RotateLeft[Range@Length@l, 1]}],
  ImageSize -> {300, 300}]

l = RandomReal[{0, .3}, 10];
lpp[l]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

You could replace your `PolarTicks` option with

```
PolarTicks -> Table[{(i - 1) (2 \[Pi])/7, i}, {i, 1, 7}]
```

or using your numerical values with

```
PolarTicks -> {{0.897, 2}, {0.897*2, 3}, {0.897*3, 4}, {0.897*4, 5}, {0.897*5, 6}, {0.897*6, 7}, {0.897*7, 1}}
```

The syntax is `{position,label}` for every tick.

```
ListPolarPlot[
Tooltip /@ {0.01422, 0.3425217, 0.30036, 0.013, 0.152, 0.3762, 
0.122}, Joined -> True, 
PlotMarkers -> Graphics@Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[0.025]], 
Axes -> {True, False}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
PolarGridLines -> {{0.897, 0.897*2, 0.897*3, 0.897*4, 0.897*5, 
0.897*6, 0.897*7}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}}, AspectRatio -> 1/1, 
ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
PolarTicks -> {{0.897, 2}, {0.897*2, 3}, {0.897*3, 4}, {0.897*4, 
5}, {0.897*5, 6}, {0.897*6, 7}, {0.897*7, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]