# ListPolarPlot broken by PlotMarkers & Joined

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.2 and fixed in 12.0**

> [CASE: 4033672] confirmed

---

## Update

I have created a fix for this issue, which can be found in my answer below.

## Note

This issue (in an even worse form) occurs in the code of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19923/listpolarplot-labelling-points-on-the-plot), but from what I could tell, this was not an issue back then, since the question asks about something else (and the answers are also broken, so I guess we can assume that this issue was introduced after that point)

## Problem description

It appears [`ListPolarPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPolarPlot.html) is completely broken when using `Joined->True` together with `PlotMarkers->Automatic`:

```
ListPolarPlot[Table[1, 10], Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Both options are used explicitly in [the documentation of `ListPolarPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPolarPlot.html), so they should work. It appears that the developers are at least partly aware of this issue, as the following example uses `Mesh->True` instead of `PlotMarkers->Automatic`:

```
ListPolarPlot[
 Table[{θ, GoldenRatio^θ}, {θ, 0, 4 Pi, 0.25}], 
 Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {r, r}, 
 PlotLabel -> GoldenRatio^θ, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Purple], Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there something I'm missing or is this just a simple bug? Also, how can I work around this properly? `Mesh` doesn't seem to be ideal for multiple curves in one plot...

Comment: Looks like it got broken in version 11; `ListPolarPlot[Table[1, {10}], Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]` works fine in version 10.4.

Comment: It appears to have been broken in 11.2, 11.1 still works as expected. I have notified WRI and will add the bug header once confirmed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have found a fix that properly restores the behavior of `ListPolarPlot` (explanation below):

```
(* execute once to fix issue *)
ListPlot@{};
If[$VersionNumber==11.2,
  Begin["System`ProtoPlotDump`"],
  Begin["System`ListPlotsDump`"]
];
SubValues@iListPlot = SubValues@iListPlot /. 
  HoldPattern[a : (graphicsoptions = _)] :> 
    (a; AppendTo[method, "OptimizePlotMarkers" -> optimizemarkers]);
End[];
```

This injects a single line into the definition of `iListPlot` to restore the proper behavior of `ListPolarPlot`:

```
(* the original example *)
ListPolarPlot[Table[1, 10], Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
(* from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19923/listpolarplot-labelling-points-on-the-plot *)
ListPolarPlot[
 Tooltip /@ {0.01422, 0.3425217, 0.30036, 0.013, 0.152, 0.3762, 
   0.122}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics@Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[0.025]], 
 Axes -> {True, False}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
 PolarGridLines -> {{0.897, 0.897*2, 0.897*3, 0.897*4, 0.897*5, 
    0.897*6, 0.897*7}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}}, PolarTicks -> None, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/1, ImageSize -> {300, 300}]
```

### Before

[image]
[image]

### After

[image]
[image]

## Explanation

**Note**: To see the definitions I'm talking about, load `` <<GeneralUtilities` `` and use `PrintDefinitions@symbol` to get a readable version of the definitions. Also, the symbols have moved from `` System`ProtoPlotDump` `` in 11.2 to `` System`ListPlotsDump` `` in 11.3 (the below always refers to the 11.3 contexts).

### The issue

- `ListPolarPlot` internally calls `ListPlot` (via `` Graphics`PolarPlotDump`listPolarPlot ``), and then transforms the result by interpreting the x-Axis as the angle and the y-Axis as the radius (see `` Graphics`PolarPlotDump`cleanup ``).
- `` Graphics`PolarPlotDump`cleanup `` only works on `GraphicsComplex`, so `` Graphics`PolarPlotDump`listPolarPlot `` calls `ListPlot` with `"OptimizePlotMarkers"->False`, which should prevent a `Normal`ization of the `GraphicsComplex` to a simple list of coordinates.
- In 11.2, the code handling `"OptimizePlotMarkers"` was moved from `` System`ListPlotsDump`iListPlot `` to `` System`ListPlotsDump`postProcessLayout ``, but the option is never properly forwarded to that function.
- This causes the `GraphicsComplex` to be `Normal`ized, which in turn causes `` Graphics`PolarPlotDump`cleanup `` to fail.

### The fix

- Since `` System`ListPlotsDump`postProcessLayout `` reads out the `method` parameter to determine the value of `"OptimizePlotMarkers"`, we simply need to add the setting to that list to forward it.
- We have to do it after `graphicsoptions` is built, since `` System`ListPlotsDump`renderLayoutProcess `` silently crashes the kernel if the `Method` option contains the `"OptimizePlotMarkers"` setting.

Answer (score 2):

As workaround you can use either [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) or [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html)

```
x[r_, t_] = r Cos[t];
y[r_, t_] = r Sin[t];

ListPlot[Table[#[GoldenRatio^θ, θ] & /@ {x, y}, {θ, 0, 
   4 Pi, 0.25}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 AspectRatio -> 1.5, 
 AxesLabel -> (#[GoldenRatio^θ, θ] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[#[GoldenRatio^θ, θ] & /@ {x, y}, {θ, 0, 4 Pi, 
   0.25}],
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic
 , AspectRatio -> 1.5, 
 AxesLabel -> (#[GoldenRatio^θ, θ] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see how I can use `PolarGridLines` and similar with this approach. But for simpler cases, this is surely an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is plot the figure with `ListPolarPlot` without using `PlotMarkers` and then replace the points in the figure with the shape you want. For example,

```
fig /. {Point[x__] :> (Circle[#, 0.03] & /@ x)}
```