# How to change plot markers in ListPolarPlot

Tags: plotting

I've been trying to draw a polar plot using the `ListPolarPlot` function with custom marker shapes. However, when I use `PlotMarkers` several errors appear (see attached screenshot). In the past I have successfully used `PlotMarkers` with `ListPlot`, so the problem seems to be `ListPolarPlot`.

[image: Screenshot showing errors when using PlotMarkers]

So far I've only been able to change the colour and size of the points by using `PlotStyle`, but cannot find a way to change their shape:

```
Data = {{0, 70}, {π/12, 45}, {π/6, 60}, {π/4, 90}, {π/2, 30}}

ListPolarPlot[Data, PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
  Joined -> False, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize -> 0.014}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can't help much without a minimal working example. This should include the smallest piece of complete working code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @Edmund, Sorry, I have added a working example along with the resulting plot.

Comment: `PlotMarkers` should work. e.g. `PlotMarkers -> \[FilledUpTriangle]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, That's exactly what I cannot do. A series of errors appear.

Comment: I cut and pasted your code, added `PlotMarkers -> \[FilledUpTriangle]` and it worked fine. I am using "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)".

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, I cannot seem to get it working. I'm using Mathematica 11.3 on Mac OS X 10.12

Comment: I just tried it on 11.3 and it fails with the same errors you reported.

Comment: does `ListPolarPlot[Data, PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
 Joined -> False, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize -> 0.014}]/. Point[x_]:>( Text["\[FilledUpTriangle]",#]&/@x)` work in your version/OS?

Comment: @kglr That works for me on 11.3 Mac OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListPolarPlot broken by PlotMarkers & Joined](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169308/listpolarplot-broken-by-plotmarkers-joined) - the exact circumstances are a bit different there, but the fix proposed there works as well for this case

Answer (score 5):

Use the option [`PlotMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html)

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Data = {{0, 70}, {π/12, 45}, {π/6, 60}, {π/4, 90}, {π/2, 30}};

ListPolarPlot[Data, PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
 Joined -> False, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize -> 0.014},
 PlotMarkers -> {Style[▲, 20]},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Per Rohit's comment post-processing `Point`s into desired text marker works in v11.3 (Mac OS):

```
ListPolarPlot[Data, 
   PolarAxes -> True, 
   PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
   Joined -> False, 
   PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize -> 0.014}
 ] /. Point[x_] :> (Text["▲", #]& /@ x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, this is a bug that was introduced in 11.2 and fixed in 12.0. The fix for versions 11.2 and 11.3 is to execute the code below once:

```
(* execute once to fix issue *)
ListPlot@{};
If[$VersionNumber==11.2,
  Begin["System`ProtoPlotDump`"],
  Begin["System`ListPlotsDump`"]
];
SubValues@iListPlot = SubValues@iListPlot /. 
  HoldPattern[a : (graphicsoptions = _)] :> 
    (a; AppendTo[method, "OptimizePlotMarkers" -> optimizemarkers]);
End[];
```

Now everything works as expected:

```
$Version
(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

Data = {{0, 70}, {π/12, 45}, {π/6, 60}, {π/4, 
    90}, {π/2, 30}};

ListPolarPlot[
 Data,
 PolarAxes -> True,
 PolarGridLines -> Automatic,
 Joined -> False,
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic},
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize -> 0.014},
 PlotMarkers -> ▲
 ]
```

[image]

An explanation of how this fix works can be found in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169308/listpolarplot-broken-by-plotmarkers-joined).

Answer (score 0):

`PlotMarkers` seems to work fine with both Mathematica v.12 (as per comments/answer posted by @Rohit Namjoshi and @Bob Hanlon, respectively) and v.10.0 (it ran perfectly when I tried it just now).
It seems to be an issue in v.11.3 where `PlotMarkers` conflicts with `PolarAxes`.

Comment: There is no version 11 or version 10. There are 10.0, 10.1, 11.0, 11.1, etc. Please be specific.