# Error bars in ListPolarPlot

Tags: plotting, data, around

I am trying to visualise my data in polar coordinates including error bars. This with Mathematica 12 and the function `Around`. However,

```
ListPolarPlot[{{Around[1, 0.2], Around[7, 2.2]}}]
```

only shows a data point without error bars. I didn't find a polar plot with according error bars anywhere so far. Is this at all possible with `ListPolarPlot`?

---

An example of the desirable output follows: (from [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_error_caps.html) )

[image]

---

Thanks for any help.

Armin

Comment: I thought it might be interesting to also note that the `ListPolarPlot` documentation lists `IntervalMarkers` as a valid option, but actually using the option generates a **General::optx** (unknown option) message (on `$Version` 13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround:

```
polarListPlotWithErrorbars[pts_, errs_] := Module[{},
  Show[
   ListPolarPlot[pts, PolarAxes -> True, 
    PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> Automatic,
     PlotStyle -> Darker[Green]],
   Table[
    PolarPlot[
     pts[[n, 2]], {th, pts[[n, 1]] - errs[[n, 1]], 
      pts[[n, 1]] + errs[[n, 1]]}, PlotStyle -> Darker[Green]], {n, 
     Length[pts]}],
   ListPolarPlot[
    Table[{{pts[[n, 1]], pts[[n, 2]] - errs[[n, 2]]}, {pts[[n, 1]], 
       pts[[n, 2]] + errs[[n, 2]]}}, {n, Length[pts]}], 
    Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Darker[Green]]
   , PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
  ]
```

With points and associated errors in `{theta, r}` dimensions

```
pts = {{0, .5}, {\[Pi]/4, 0.7}, {\[Pi]/2, .8}}
errs = {{.1, .05}, {.2, .1}, {.1, .04}}

polarListPlotWithErrorbars[pts, errs]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Looking forward to implement it in a couple of days. :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer but instead a temporary workaround by converting the data points to cartesian coordinates:

```
transform = 
  CoordinateTransformData["Polar" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];

p0 = {Around[1, 0.2], Around[7, 2.2]};

pts = Table[p0 + {i, 0}, {i, 0, 9}];

(*note `CoordinateTransform` takes {r,theta} pairs while ListPolarPlot takes {theta,r} pairs so we have to Reverse each pair*)
new = transform[Reverse[#]] & /@ pts;
```

Now we can compare the polar plot and the transformed cartesian plot, and we see they're the same, but we are now capable of using `IntervalMarkers`
(note: for the nice PolarPlot formatting, I used Lukas Lang's answer from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207977/72953)):

```
polar = ListPolarPlot[pts, PolarAxes -> True, 
   PolarGridLines -> Automatic, Joined -> False, 
   PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 12}, 
   PlotStyle -> Darker@Green];
cart = ListPlot[new, PlotStyle -> White, 
   IntervalMarkersStyle -> Darker@Green, Axes -> False];
Show[cart, polar, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are still some shortcomings with this:

1. The uncertainty intervals are now cartesian, so they aren't really showing a curved "angle" of uncertainty if that makes sense. This is probably the biggest issue
2. The plot looks really busy. This can probably be fixed by decreasing font size, and maybe spacing out the `PolarGridLines` more.

Comment: Thank you. But the error bars in the respective coordinates are what I am looking for. I will try to explicate more precisely with my next question. 
Thanks also for the note on IntervalMarkers above.